# Why is my for loop only iterating once?

Tags: c, for-loop, iteration

I am writing a Hangman program. I'm having trouble with my function which handles a character guess from the user. The issue I have is that my for loop only seems to be iterating once and I cannot work out why. This is an assignment so I'm not asking for specific code in reply but a point in the right direction would be good. Thanks, here's the function:

```
void charGuess(char *ch,char *word, int aCount)
{
    char *chr;
    int theResult, i, k, lossCount = 0;
    char aArray[aCount+1];
    char *current;

    for(k=0;k<aCount;k++)
    {
        aArray[k] = '_';
    }

    printf("\nThe char count: %d\n", aCount); //the "aCount" which ive passed in works

    while(1){
        for(i=0; i<aCount; i++) //this loop only iterates once. "aCount" is never 0 when i pass it.
        {
            current = word[i];
            printf("the current char is %c", current);

            if(strcmp(current, ch))
            {
                printf("\ni is: %d\n", i);
                aArray[i] = current;
                printf("%c", aArray[i]);
                displayNewDashes(aCount, aArray);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                lossCount++;
                hangTheMan(lossCount);
                printf("Loss count: %d", lossCount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what value for `aCount` do you pass to the function?

Comment: when you `break`, you leave the loop...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg "aCount" varies each time I run the program as it is the character count for a random word generated for hangman.

Comment: `current = word[i];` - ugh what? `word` is a `char *`, so `word[i]` is a `char`. Assigning it to a `char *` (which `current` is) doesn't make any sense at all. Also, you can't compare characters using `strcmp()`. You can use the normal `==` operator for that purpose (do you even read the documentation of functions you're trying to use???)

Comment: are u aware that strcmp(current,ch) return 0 if current equal ch; and non zero if current differs from ch

Comment: The number of things wrong in this code dwarfs the fact the loop leaves early. You need to review how pointers in C work. Ex: `printf("the current char is %c", current);` is incorrect. As is `current = word[i];` Cranking up the warnings to obscene levels and *addressing them* will help greatly.

Comment: @Floris ive tried without the break statement aswell and it doesn't work :(

Comment: You need to identify end conditions (win, loss) and then break.  At this point, you have only identified correct letter picked and incorrect letter picked.

Comment: displayNewDashes() and handTheMan() should return 1 (or something) when an end condition is reached, like the word is guessed or the man is hung.  THEN you can break.

Answer (score 3):

Since you state this is for an assignment and you are looking for pointers, here are a few basic debugging steps.

1) turn on all the warnings your compiler is capable of generating, and fix your code until the warnings have gone away. Right now the above yield (with gcc):

```
hang.c:20:21: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to
      'char *' from 'char'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
            current = word[i];
                    ^ ~~~~~~~
                      &
hang.c:21:46: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'char *' [-Wformat]
            printf("the current char is %c", current);
                                        ~~   ^~~~~~~
                                        %s
hang.c:26:27: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to
      'char' from 'char *'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
                aArray[i] = current;
                          ^ ~~~~~~~
```

2) Step through the code with a debugger. If your compiler doesn't have a debugger, get a new compiler. Seriously.

3) If you *still* can't figure out why your loops are not behaving, generate the smallest example that still has the unexpected behavior. Very likely, making a small example will expose the problem.

4) If you *still* can't see it, document all of the above in your question - and we will gladly give you the hint(s) needed to finish it.

Comment: A couple of hints. Don't use `strcmp` when you are looking for a character match. Pass the guess as a `char` (not `char*`), and loop over all positions of the string: `for(ii=0; ii<aCount; ii++) {if (word[ii]==ch) {// match};`

Comment: ... or use `strchr`, which does the same but is less typing and does not need another local variable.